# How do I check if an std::variant can hold a certain type

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a class with an `std::variant` in it. This `std::variant` type is only allowed to hold a specific list of types.

I have template functions which allow the user of the class to insert various values into an `std::unordered_map`, the map holds values of this variant type. I.e., the user is only allowed to insert values if it's type is in the specific list of types. However, I don't want the user to be able to define this list of types themselves.

```
class GLCapabilities
{
public:
    using VariantType = std::variant<GLint64>;  // in future this would have other types

    template <typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<???> AddCapability(const GLenum parameterName)
    {
        if(m_capabilities.count(parameterName) == 0)
        {
            /*... get correct value of type T ... */
            m_capabilities.insert(parameterName,value);
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<???,T> GetCapability(const GLenum parameterName) const
    {
        auto itr = m_capabilities.find(parameterName);
        if(std::holds_alternative<T>(*itr))
            return std::get<T>(*itr);

        return T;
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<GLenum,VariantType> m_capabilities;
};
```

You'll see in the above where there's the `???`, how can I check? Some combination of `std::disjunction` with `std::is_same`?

Like

```
std::enable_if<std::disjunction<std::is_same<T,/*Variant Types???*/>...>>
```

To make it clear, I'd prefer to not have to check against each allowed type manually.

Comment: Wouldn't `m_capabilities.insert(` simply fail to compile is an invalid value is passed? It would seem to me that simple duck typing is the easy answer here. It would be a different matter if you used `emplace()`, obviously, or do you want to prevent any implicit casting whatsoever?

Comment: Because I'll be using various OpenGL types, like `GLuint` or `GLint` etc, implicit casting could be a problem; so yes, I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: In Boost.Variant we had `VariantType::types` to get an `mpl::list` of types. Then you could use `mpl::contains`. That seems to be absent in `std::variant`, one has to implement it by deducing the template parameters and using variadic templates.

Comment: Can someone explain `std::enable_if` to me? I don't get it

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Edit:** I actually dig your `std::disjunction` idea, and it absolutely works. You just have to extract the type list using template specialization.

My entire old-school recursive mess becomes simply:

```
template<typename T, typename VARIANT_T>
struct isVariantMember;

template<typename T, typename... ALL_T>
struct isVariantMember<T, std::variant<ALL_T...>> 
  : public std::disjunction<std::is_same<T, ALL_T>...> {};
```

**Original answer:** Here's a simple template that accomplishes this. It works by returning `false` for empty type lists. For non-empty lists, it returns `true` if the first type passes `std::is_same<>`, and recursively invokes itself with all but the first type otherwise.

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <variant>

// Main lookup logic of looking up a type in a list.
template<typename T, typename... ALL_T>
struct isOneOf : public std::false_type {};

template<typename T, typename FRONT_T, typename... REST_T>
struct isOneOf<T, FRONT_T, REST_T...> : public 
  std::conditional<
    std::is_same<T, FRONT_T>::value,
    std::true_type,
    isOneOf<T, REST_T...>
  >::type {};

// Convenience wrapper for std::variant<>.
template<typename T, typename VARIANT_T>
struct isVariantMember;

template<typename T, typename... ALL_T>
struct isVariantMember<T, std::variant<ALL_T...>> : public isOneOf<T, ALL_T...> {};

// Example:
int main() {
  using var_t = std::variant<int, float>;

  bool x = isVariantMember<int, var_t>::value; // x == true
  bool y = isVariantMember<double, var_t>::value; // y == false

  return 0;
}
```

N.B. Make sure you strip cv and reference qualifiers from T before invoking this (or add the stripping to the template itself). It depends on your needs, really.

Answer (score 7):

Since you're already using C++17, fold-expressions make this easier:

```
template <class T, class U> struct is_one_of;

template <class T, class... Ts> 
struct is_one_of<T, std::variant<Ts...>>
: std::bool_constant<(std::is_same_v<T, Ts> || ...)>
{ };
```

For added readability, you could add an alias in your class:

```
class GLCapabilities
{
public:
    using VariantType = std::variant<GLint64>;  // in future this would have other types
    template <class T> using allowed = is_one_of<T, VariantType>;

    template <typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<allowed<T>{}> AddCapability(const GLenum parameterName)
    { ... }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very handy. Weirdly enough, in my case it didn't compile as is (MSVC 16.7.3, C++17 enabled).
I had to change the enable_if like that : std::enable_if_t<allowed<T>::value>
Not sure why though !

Answer (score 5):

```
template <class T> struct type {};
template <class T> constexpr type<T> type_v{};

template <class T, class...Ts, template<class...> class Tp>
constexpr bool is_one_of(type<Tp<Ts...>>, type<T>) {
    return (std::is_same_v<Ts, T> || ...); 
}
```

Then use `is_one_of(type_v<VariantType>, type_v<T>)` in the `enable_if`.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid using `std::enable_if_t` and use instead a classic `decltype`-based SFINAE expressions like the one in the following example:

```
#include<variant>
#include<utility>

struct S {
    using type = std::variant<int, double>;

    template<typename U>
    auto f()
    -> decltype(std::declval<type>().emplace<U>(), void()) {
        // that's ok
    }
};

int main() {
    S s;
    s.f<int>();
    //s.f<char>();
}
```

If you toggle the comment to the last line, you get a compile-time time error for `char` isn't a type accepted by your variant.

The pros of this solution is that it's simple and you don't have neither to include `type_traits` (granted, you have to include `utility`) nor to use a support class to get a bool value to test out of it.
Of course, you can adjust the return type accordingly with your requirements for each function.

See it up and running on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5vovgjXbcpq7ZvQb).

---

Otherwise, if you can stick with the limitations of `std::holds_alternative` (the call is ill-formed if the type compares more than once in the parameters list of the variant), note that it's a `constexpr` function and it just does what you want:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<variant>
#include<utility>

struct S {
    using type = std::variant<int, double>;

    template<typename U>
    std::enable_if_t<std::holds_alternative<U>(type{})>
    f() {
        // that's ok
    }
};

int main() {
    S s;
    s.f<int>();
    //s.f<char>();
}
```

As above, toggle the comment and you'll get a compile-time error as expected.

See it up and running on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/p3bw8JE3ftORA5mF).

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>


template <typename, typename... T0ToN>
struct is_one_of;

template <typename T>
struct is_one_of<T> : public std::false_type
{
};

template <typename T, typename... T1toN>
struct is_one_of<T, T, T1toN...> : public std::true_type
{
};

template <typename T, typename P, typename... T1toN>
struct is_one_of<T, P, T1toN...> : is_one_of<T, T1toN...>
{
};

template <typename Type, typename ... Others>
struct is_in_variant : public std::false_type {};

template <typename Type, typename ... Others>
struct is_in_variant<Type, std::variant<Others...>> : public is_one_of<Type, Others...>
{};


int main()
{
    std::variant<int, float> v;
    return is_in_variant<double, std::variant<int, float>>::value ? 4 : 8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using SFINAE by constructing the `VariantType` from the `T` type.

```
template <typename T, typename = VariantType(std::declval<T>())>
void AddCapability(T const& t); // not sure how you want to use it.
```

Or use `std::is_constructible<VariantType, T>`. After all you probably want to know if you can assign/initialize from the type, not if type is actually one of the variant types (which is more restrictive).

Comment: Implicit conversions will kick in, which the OP explicitely wants to avoid.

Comment: @Frank. Ok, yes, it wasn't clear from the question. I guess that is an unnecessary restriction. The OP should reconsider that arbitrary restriction.

Comment: You should read the comment chain in the OP, which goes over why he needs it.