# Output for directory_entry conflicts with overloaded ostream operator<< for class with variant

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, variant, std-filesystem

I have a project where I print `std::filesystem::directory_entry` from directory_iterator. On the other side, I have a completely independent class with overload `std::ostream& operator<<`, that has a templated constructor, which initializes a `std::variant` member.

```
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

typedef std::variant<long, std::string> VarType;

class Var {
  VarType _value;
public:
  template<typename T>
  Var(T value) : _value{value} {
  }
};    

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Var&) {
  return stream;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << std::filesystem::directory_entry() << "\n";//tigger compling error
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation fails:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Var::Var(T) [with T =
std::filesystem::__cxx11::directory_entry]’: main.cpp:25:49:  
required from here main.cpp:11:30: error: no matching function for
call to ‘std::variant<long int, double,
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
std::allocator<char> > >::variant(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’ 
Var(T value) : _value{value} {
... several pages of output ...
```

It seems it tries to wrap `directory_entry` into `Var`, before sending it to `cout`, but I am not sure.

**Could you please explain what is actually going on and why code is wrong?**

I tested around. For the issue, it seems to do no matter what I put into `variant`, even a single variant is ill. This one

```
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

typedef std::variant<long, std::string> VarType;

class Var {
  VarType _value;
public:
  template<typename T>
  Var(T value) : _value{value} {
  }
};    

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const VarType&) {
  return stream;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << std::filesystem::directory_entry() << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

works fine. If I move `_value` initialization into c-tor body compilation fails with the same logical error but for `operator=`, at least it is consistent. Evidently it works with non-templated c-tor.

If I move the implementation of `ostream& operator<<` into a separate unit and defines it as a friend of `Var`, compilation passes (it is a kind of suitable workaround, yet it was not supposed `operator<<` has access to private of class). However, it fails if I simply separate and do not make friends.

main.cpp:

```
#include "var.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main() {
  std::cout << std::filesystem::directory_entry() << "\n";
  std::cout << Var(1l) << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

var.hpp:

```
#include <variant>
#include <ostream>

typedef std::variant<long, std::string> VarType;

class Var {
  VarType _value;
public:
  template<typename T>
  Var(T value) : _value{value} {
  }   
  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Var&);    //works
};    
//std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Var&);    //instead above does not works
```

var.cpp:

```
#include "var.hpp"

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Var&) {
  return stream;
}
```

That makes me completely lost. Assuming that it tries to invoke `Var` c-tor on `<<` here should be no difference.
**Why such change does matter?**

I build with g++8.4 (`g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp var.cpp -lstdc++fs`, also I tried clang7.0 with a similar result).

Comment: [Compiles fine with Clang trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/rq169o), and the error I see with Clang 7.x is not similar to your posted error, it complains about the variant having no matching constructor for initialization.
`<source>:11:18: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'VarType' (aka 'variant<long, basic_string<char> >')

  Var(T value) : _value{value} {

                 ^     ~~~~~~~`

Comment: By similar, I meant that clang also tries to initialize `Var` with  `directory_entry`. If it's fixed in trunk, should I consider that as a known compiler bug? Thanks for godbolt link.

Comment: No, it isn't. But if you want to avoid that error, you should mark your constructor as explicit.

Comment: In other words,  `directory_entry` does not have an explicit `ostream& operator<<` and thus conversation has to be used anyway. The compiler chooses my one, that is ill and SFINAE does not help. Explicit solves this issue. Trunk compiler version has  ostream& operator<< for  directory_entry, the compiler does not look for conversion, does not it? That explains most of the questions.  
Why friend makes a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Mansoor's hints, I think I found out.

**C-tor**

This code is dangerous.

```
class Var {
public:
  template<typename T>
  Var(T value)  {
  }  
};
```

Avoid this.
The compiler will try to substitute such c-tor in any implicit conversion where `Var` is visible and may be suitable.
Mark c-tor as `explicit` is the most straightforward way to restrict such wild substitution. SFINAE and `enable_if` can be other ways to restrict substitutions.

And the ill substitution is exactly what breaks complication in my case because in old complies `directory_entry` does not have a direct definition of `ostream<<`. The compiler looks for a converter and finds suitable `Var`.  Which can be instantiated but can not be complied. The latter is good because if it could, the error was untraceable.

There is a patch https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-patches/2018-06/msg01084.html about 2018 (or maybe it is soon fixed on it) that introduced explicit `ostream << directory_entry`.

Before that  `directory_entry` could be converted to `path`  with implicit c-tor like that

```
template<typename _Source,
     typename _Require = _Path<_Source>>
  path(_Source const& __source, format = auto_format)
```

That is why  `ostream << directory_entry` works if no `ostream<<` is explicitly defined.

**Friend**

Friend actually scopes converter visibility. That works also

```
class Var {
  VarType _value;
public:
  template<typename T>
  Var(T value) : _value{value} {
  }
  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Var&) {
    return stream;
  }
};
```

But if `std::ostream&` is declared as friend and definition (or other declaration) is visible for `ostream << directory_entry` when it breaks complication again because of other declaration is visible for wild substitution. That explains why separation into several units and using friend created a workaround.

**SFINAE**

SFINAE does not check the function body. It works only with declarations. `_value{value}` is body. To invoke SFINAE c-tor  should be like

```
  template< class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<T, long>,  std::is_same<T, std::string>>>>
  Var(T value) : _value{value} {
  }
```

Brilliant ideas how to deal with `std::variant` depended c-tor can be dug out here:
[How do I check if an std::variant can hold a certain type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45892170/how-do-i-check-if-an-stdvariant-can-hold-a-certain-type/45892305) .